# display all elements in a nested cell array (with character entries)

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I have the following:

```
a = 

{1x1 cell}    {1x1 cell}    {1x1 cell}    {1x1 cell}
```

where:

```
a{:}

ans = 

'a'


ans = 

'a'


ans = 

'c'


ans = 

'a'
```

I want to have the characters: `a  a  c  a`

Since I need the characters to print using `fprintf`

`fprintf` won't accept `a{:}`

If I do `a{1}{:}` will consider only the first character a

How to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need the character vector 'aaca', you can use this:

```
a = {{'a'}, {'a'}, {'c'}, {'a'}};

a_CharVector = cellfun(@(x) char(x), a);
```

If you want the character vector 'a a c a ', you can use `regexprep` to add the spaces:

```
a_CharVectorWithSpaces = regexprep((cellfun(@(x) char(x), a)), '(.)', '$1 ');
```

To print a a c a with spaces and newline you can use this:

```
fprintf([ regexprep((cellfun(@(x) char(x), a)), '(.)', '$1 '), '\n' ]);
```

**Edit: unnecessary anonymous function removed. `@(x)` is unnecessary in this case.**

To get character vector 'aaca' this works:

```
a_CharVector = cellfun(@char, a);
```

And to get character vector 'a a c a ' you can use this:

```
a_CharVectorWithSpaces = regexprep((cellfun(@char, a)), '(.)', '$1 ');
```

To printf a a c a with newline:

```
fprintf([ regexprep((cellfun(@char, a)), '(.)', '$1 '), '\n' ]);
```

Comment: `@(x)` is syntax for constructing an anonymous function. However, in this case it is not necessary, as `@char` is sufficient. I edited my answer to add the solution without `@(x)` syntax. For more info about anonymous functions you can check [MATLAB documentation about anonymous functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f4-70115.html). Anonymous functions are quite useful with `cellfun` and `arrayfun` in some cases.

Comment: thanks. @nrz I am frankly using Fprintf to save to text file using your code it is now: fileID = fopen('a.txt', 'at'); fprintf(fileID, '%2.8s \n', cellfun(@(x) char(x), a)); fclose(fileID);

Comment: So, when you use `@(x)` syntax together with `cellfun`, `x` gets all the values of the cell array one by one, so first `x` is `{'a'}`, then `x` is again `{'a'}`, then `{'c'}` ... and in this case `char` is applied to all these values `x` gets, creating a character vector of them.

Comment: You're welcome. To separate the characters I have used `regexprep`. You may want to read [MATLAB documentation about regular expressions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f0-42649.html). `regexprep(CharVector, '(.)', '$1 ');` replaces each character of `CharVector` (expression `'(.)'` ) with its original character (`$1` in the replace string) and a space (space in the replace string) on its right side. Naturally this means that you'll get extra space in the end. To avoid this, you can replace it with another `regexprep` or using `CharVector(end) = [];` after `regexprep`.

Comment: did not work @nrz ??? Error using ==> cellfun
Non-scalar in Uniform output, at index 1, output 1.
Set 'UniformOutput' to false.

Comment: deviations{1}

ans = 

    [0]    [0.4000]    [0]    [0]    [0]    [0]    [0]    [0]    [0]    [0]

Comment: can you help me as the next post write it to save to file @nrz?