# display all elements in a nested cell array (with integer entries)

Tags: matlab, cell-array

This is related to the post

[display all elements in a nested cell array (with character entries)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10148955/display-all-elements-in-a-nested-cell-array-with-character-entries/10149478#10149478)

with a change where entries are characters. A new question was asked for clarity.

Now :

a =

```
{1x10 cell}    {1x10 cell}    {1x10 cell}    {1x10 cell}
```

a{:}=

```
ans = [0]    [0.4000]    [0]    [0]    [0]    [0]    [0]    [0]    [0]    [0]

ans = [0]    [0]    [0.2000]    [0]    [0.2000]    [0]    [0.2000]    [0]    [0]    [0]

ans = [0]    [0]    [0]    [0]    [0]    [0.2000]    [0]    [0]    [0.2000]    [0.2000]

ans = [0]    [0.2000]    [0]    [0]    [0]    [0]    [0]    [0.4000]    [0]    [0.2000]
```

the answer to the previous was:

```
fileID = fopen('a.txt', 'at');
fprintf(fileID, '%2.8s \n', cellfun(@(x) char(x), a));
fclose(fileID);
```

How to solve it now?
want to print:

```
           0  0.4  0    0  0   0  0   0  0  0
           0  0    0.2  0  0.2 0  0.2 0  0  0
           .
           .
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to do it:

```
a = { { 0, 0.4000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0.2000, 0, 0.2000, 0, 0.2000, 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2000, 0, 0, 0.2000, 0.2000 }, { 0, 0.2000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.4000, 0, 0.2000 }};

fileID = fopen('a.txt', 'at');

fprintf(fileID, [ (regexprep((regexprep((regexprep((regexprep(mat2str(cell2mat(cellfun(@cell2mat, a, 'UniformOutput', false)')), '(0 )' , '$1  ')), '[', '')), ']', '')), ';', '\n')), '\n' ]);

fclose(fileID);
```

**Edit: alternative solution. In this one shorter lines are padded with spaces.**

```
CharMatrix = char(regexprep(cellfun(@mat2str, (cellfun(@cell2mat, a, 'UniformOutput', false)'), 'UniformOutput', false), '0 ', '0   '));
CharMatrix(CharMatrix == ']') = ' ';
CharMatrix(:,1) = [];
CharMatrix(:,end) = '\';
CharMatrix(:,end+1) = 'n';
fileID = fopen('a.txt', 'at');
fprintf(fileID, reshape(CharMatrix', 1, []));
fclose(fileID);
```

Comment: thanks @nrz. Well just to give credit to all the above answer was correct too

Answer (score 2):

I seem to recall if you put the values into an array, it will do the conversion appropriately. I don't have Matlab to test it, but this should work.

```
[a{:}]
```